# URLSession: Follow a redirect from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: swift, google-sheets, urlsession

I'm using google forms to gather data, and the user can upload an image. This gets stored in a google spreadsheet, which is published to the web, which I then grab as a json file.

In the json, the image URL comes to me in the form: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxx`.

If I `curl -I` that URL, I get a status code of `HTTP/2 307`. If I `curl -L` it redirects, and I get what I want.

But if I use that URL with `URLSession`, I get a 200 response:

```
po print(response)
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600002d3e460> { URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxx/view?usp=drive_open } { Status Code: 200, Headers { etc...
```

That's the URL I want! Why doesn't `URLSession`, who's "default is to follow redirects", correctly redirect and get me that page? Do I have to parse out the desired URL, then make a second `URLSession` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be easier than I thought. Image URLs that are stored on a google spreadsheet (or at least ones that are initially stored from a google forms doc) are in this format:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M-BjN3..nonce..lbl9
```

If we change the string `open?id` to `uc?id` the string is transformed into a valid URL that points to the image.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1M-BjN3..nonce..lbl9
```

In Swift:

```
let corrected = imageUrl.replacingOccurrences(of: "open?id", with: "uc?id")
```